# PostgreSQL command Automation in batch script

Tags: postgresql

I need to automate the below commands through batch job, is there a way to do it. Currently command prompt is stopping after executing the first step(`psql -U nrgadmin -d enwdb`). Inside the `enwdb` database, I need to manually execute the steps from begin to commit. Any help would be appreciated.

```
psql -U nrgadmin -d enwdb;

 begin;
 alter schema asset_enw rename to asset_enw_backup;
 alter schema asset_import rename to asset_enw;
 alter table enw.geom rename to geom_backup;
 alter table enw.geom_backup set schema asset_enw_backup;
 alter table import.geom set schema enw;
 commit;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your commands in a script file and use the `-f` option of `psql` while running it.

```
psql -U nrgadmin -d enwdb -f myscript.sql
```

Or, if you are in a Unix environment, you could put it all in a here document in a shell script and run the shell script.

```
#!/bin/sh
psql -U nrgadmin -d enwdb <<EOF
BEGIN;
alter schema asset_enw rename to asset_enw_backup;
#other statements
#--
COMMIT;
EOF
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion Kaushik. Amended the shell script based on your suggestion. It worked fine. Thank you.